# "they do not have chunks of rotting flesh from their meals on their teeth, cultivating bacteria."

Tags: meaning

I was reading this page.[1] It's about Komodo Dragons, an animal you should really study about them if you didn't do that yet.

> The notorious Komodos are no dirtier than any other species he’s
>   studied, he says. “After they are done feeding, they will spend 10 to
>   15 minutes lip-licking and rubbing their head in the leaves to clean
>   their mouth… Unlike people have been led to believe, they do not have
>   chunks of rotting flesh from their meals on their teeth, **cultivating
>   bacteria.**”

The problem is with the bold part. If I'm not wrong, "they do not have chunks of rotting flesh from their meals on their teeth, cultivating bacteria." means "they do not have chunks of rotting flesh from their meals on their teeth **that leads to** cultivating bacteria." Is that right?

[1]. http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/science-sushi/2013/06/25/here-be-dragons-the-mythic-bite-of-the-komodo/#.Ucq2z_n3pz1

Comment: The sentence is grammatically correct. Confusion is in it is written in passive vs. active voice, which can make it unclear. Generally, write in active voice. it's clear; concise--easy to understand. For passive, just find the sentence's subject, verb, and object [Kodomos are[not] dirty].  ...but a general belief is they are. Stating "Kodomo dragons are clean" isn't going to cut it, so, convincing the reader by introducing  information to show they are becomes just as important as the subject. A writer makes the sentence passive voice to do this. Review active vs. passive voice may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the comma to separate the latter chunk of the sentence "**...,cultivating bacteria"** is what throws most off in this case. But in this case it is more of a writing style that causes the confusion.

To cut my work short, **yes you are right** and the statement goes to counter the popular belief that Komodo dragons have a mouth full of harmful bacteria.

Reasoning (If you wish to confirm my logic)

By the sentence itself the indication is toward the cleanliness of the Komodo dragon, countering popular belief, due to the initial words

> "The notorious Komodos are **no dirtier than any other species** he's studied,....."

Due to the comma creating some confusion, I just took a minute to confirm the cleanliness of the Komodo dragons as proven [here](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/science-sushi/2013/06/25/here-be-dragons-the-mythic-bite-of-the-komodo/#.VDZvFPmSyNI) and [here](http://phenomena.nationalgeographic.com/2013/06/27/the-myth-of-the-komodo-dragons-dirty-mouth/). Then I returned back to confirm the initial logical approach with verified data from other sources.

Sorry to include proofing but I just wanted to show that you are correct and the English used there is correct too on authoritative sources other than my humble opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There's an ambiguity in the structure of the sentence that must be resolved by context.

The structure indicates that "cultivating bacteria" is the result of what precedes. But it's made ambiguous by the "they don't". Is the final clause the result that would follow if they did the thing that they don't do, or is it the result of not doing it?

Consider (let me simplify the sentence to get to the point): "They have rotting flesh on their teeth, cultivating bacteria." The presence of the rotting flesh results in cultivating bacteria.

But, "They don't have rotting flesh on their teeth, cultivating bacteria." Versus, "They don't have rotting flesh on their teeth, resulting in good dental health." Both sentences are grammatically valid. In the first case, the context would tell us that having rotting flesh on their teeth cultivates bacteria. In the second case, not having rotting flesh results in good dental health. The only way to know which is meant is to understand the subject being discussed. I'm assuming here that having rotting flesh on your teeth would be bad for your dental health, so the intended meaning seems obvious.

I'd avoid using this sort of construction if your intent is to say something where it is not necessarily obvious to the reader which is meant, or especially if you are saying something that is contrary to what most readers would expect. Like if your intent was to say that the latest medical research has shown that, in fact, having rotting flesh on your teeth is good for you, I wouldn't word it this way as readers will be confused.

Comment: Yeah I completely like your take on it too. I feel that the author's structuring was a bit faulty as it created a greater deal of ambiguity than providing facts and information

Answer (score 0):

This sentence pattern in English can seem odd at first because it means the opposite of a similar pattern

```
  The raw fish lay on the picnic table, drawing flies.
```

When you realize it's an ellipsis of "that is|was" or "in a manner that is|was" it becomes clearer.

```
The motel room did not have a light bulb near the door, attracting moths.

Komodos do not have rotting flesh on their teeth, cultivating bacteria.”
```

There are times when the immediate context will reveal the meaning:

```
He did not sing on key, pleasing the choir-master.
```

and times when it won't:

```
He did not speak loudly, upsetting his grandfather.
```

An editor might rewrite:

```
The motel room did not have near the door a light bulb attracting moths.
Komodos do not have on their teeth rotting flesh cultivating bacteria.
```